# Error bar fine-tuning in gnuplot

Tags: matplotlib, gnuplot, bar-chart

I am trying to give different colors to the error bars in a bar plot using gnuplot, but I couldn't. Some of the default color combinations between the bar on which the error line sits are not good. I tried in python and got what I wanted, but would like to get a similar output using gnuplot.

[image: What I have now from gnuplot]
[image: What I would like]

The top picture is produced using the following MWE:

```
reset
set term postscript eps size 5.5,4.5 enhanced color font 'Arial-Bold' 25
set output 'check.eps'
set style fill solid 0.3 noborder
set bars front
set key horizontal Left reverse noenhanced autotitles nobox
set style histogram errorbars linewidth 9
set style data histograms
set xlabel " " 
set xtics rotate by -45
set xlabel offset character 0, -1, 0
set yrange [0:100]
set ylabel "%" 
plot \
    newhistogram "label 1",'check.mat' \
    using 2:3:4:xtic(1) t "M1", \
         '' u 6:7:8 t "M2",\
    newhistogram "label 2", '' u 10:11:12:xtic(1) t "M1",\
        '' u 14:15:16:xtic(1) t "M2",\
    newhistogram "label 3", '' u 14:15:16:xtic(1) t "M1",\
        '' u 18:19:20:xtic(1) t "M2" lc rgb "black"
quit
```

I produced the bottom picture following the example given here: [python matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html). The colors for the error lines can be controlled using the variable **ecolor** in python. Do we have something similar in gnuplot?

I also don't understand why gnuplot is giving me dotted error lines for some of the cases. Is it possible to make them all solid?

I am beginner in gnuplot, so any help is greatly appreciated!